# Probability, Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Can anyone please help me with the problem given below.

If you receive on average 2 spam emails per day, what is the probability that you receive at most 2 spam emails on a given day?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the variance.

Comment: we only have that $E(spam/day)=2$ some information is missing. For example the probability distribution of spam email. Is it $50\%$ spam or no-spam or some other distribution?

Comment: Please use a more specific title and append your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

Note: $X\sim P(2)$. The required probability is:
$$P(X\le 2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\\
\frac{2^0\cdot e^{-2}}{0!}+\frac{2^1\cdot e^{-2}}{1!}+\frac{2^2\cdot e^{-2}}{2!}=0.6767.$$

Comment: Why exactly the Poisson distribution?

Comment: Logic_Problem_42, "on average 2 spam emails per day". [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) it gives similar example with mails.

Comment: The problem does not give us enough information to conclude that the distribution is Poisson, but it is a plausible assumption.

Comment: awkward, agreed, yes, under the assumption it follows the Poisson distribution. Thank you for comment.

Comment: (+1) I suspect the Poisson distribution has been recently covered in the text or in class. \\ In R statistical software, where `ppois` is a Poisson CDF, `ppois(2, 2)` returns 0.6766764. By calculator, it is convenient to express this as $e^{-2}(1 + 2 + 2).$